# I want keep the some page with ajax

Tags: ajax

I do not want to change pages, I want to keep it, why redirect this ajax?:

```
$('#add-user').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/evaluacion/usuariosSeleccionados",
      data: { 
              fact: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem("evaluacion")),
              seleccionados: JSON.stringify(yourArray)
            },
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) {
        document.open("text/html", "replace");                          
        document.write(data);
        document.close();
        window.location.href="/evaluacion/agregarUsuarios"// esto hago para que se quede en la misma pagina

      },
      error: function(err) {
        var msg = 'Status: ' + err.status + ': ' + err.responseText;

      }
    });
```

my link on html is

```
a(href="" id='add-user' class='btn btn-primary') agregar usuarios
```

Comment: why are you using `document.open, write, close` and `window.location` inside ajax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `document.write()` and `document.close()`? Inside of jQuery especially? Do you intend to replace the entire content of the page once the .ajax query is complete? That's probably why your page is reloading.

You should add some kind of `<div>` for the .ajax function `success`, and then put the output passed through with `data` inside the div.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tag has a property which will makes page to redirect every time you click it. In your case, because href is blank so it is reloading the page. Prevent the execution process in your event handler using `event.preventDefault` and it will not reload. 
Also, in your success callback, you are trying to redirect the page explicitly `window.location.href="/evaluacion/agregarUsuarios"` to a new URL.